# Randomize list with seed

Tags: c#, random

I'm looking for a way to randomize a List using a seed. What I want to achieve by this is controlled randomization. In other words to make sure that a list is always randomized in the same order if I use the same seed to do it.

I'm currently using this code:

```
string arbitrarySeed = "someValue";
System.Random random = new System.Random(BitConverter.ToInt32(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(arbitrarySeed), 0));
List<object> randomizedOptions = items?.OrderBy(o => random.Next()).ToList();
```

Which seems a bit overcomplicated so I'm looking for a more elegant way to handle this.

I know that randomizing is this way is not actually very random, but I don't need it to be true randomness. Something that comes close will do fine.

Comment: Why do you think this is overcomplicated? It seems like the simplest way of doing what you need, which is take string -> make int seed -> generate randoms to order another list by.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using a string as a seed instead of an integer?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi It felt like I was doing too many steps to get to where I wanted, but maybe you're right and there isn't a way to simplify anything

Comment: Your over-complication is not using an integer directly.

Comment: @jdweng the actual seed I'm using is a string from elsewhere in the application that I can't change

Comment: Note that [`BitConverter.ToInt32`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.toint32) will only take the first 4 bytes of the array you pass in, so "someValue" and "someValue2" will give you the same seed.

Comment: How "consistent" do you need it to be? You could use `new System.Random(arbitrarySeed.GetHashCode())` but it may not be stable across .NET versions or implementations.

Comment: It's only two lines of code (since the seed actually comes from elsewhere), so I don't think you'll get much simpler than that. Is it working ok, or is there an issue with what you have?

Comment: @DStanley both of your comments are a great help! I want to use the entire string and not just the first 4 bytes. I'll look into using `GetHashCode()` instead. Thanks! If you put your suggestions as an answer I can approve it so the question can be resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how "consistent" you need the generated series to be, you could use [`string.GetHashCode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.gethashcode):

```
string arbitrarySeed = "someValue";
System.Random random = new System.Random(arbitrarySeed.GetHashCode());
List<object> randomizedOptions = items?.OrderBy(o => random.Next()).ToList();
```

`GetHashCode` is not guaranteed to be consistent across .NET versions or implementations (e.g. Linux, Windows, macOS) but if you need localized consistency it may work for you.

Also note that `BitConverter.ToInt32` will only take 4 bytes of the array you pass in, so "someValue" and "someValue2" would give you the same seed value.